# Finding the centerline of a polygon of latitude/longitude coordinates

Tags: geospatial

I have a set of data (lat/lon coordinates) describing a polygon tracking a road.  The data can be presented in several forms including GeoSJON, KML, WKT, WKB, a simple 2 dimensional vector of doubles, or most any other format.

My objective is to find the centerline of that polygon in a returned vector of cordinates and I would like to do so as directly as possible, i,e, call a 'function' passing the data and receiving back the result.

I would like to do this in C#, but a library or such in C/C++ would be fine.

I've been through MAT, "skeletonizing", and several others but with limited knowledge of what is discussed in those sources, I am looking for a simplified solution, a 'cookbook' if you will.

Regards,
Jim